# Setting static IP for eth0 without router or dhcp

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, ethernet

I have a Sungrow inverter I'd like to connect to. The inverter only has the option to change the ip and subnet (192.168.1.239). My RPi (Stretch) is physically connected to the inverter and I have set the RPi to have a static IP (192.168.1.6)but I cannot connect or even ping the inverter. I have a wireless router providing dhcp (192.168.1.100-150). The wlan0 is connected to the router via a static ip (192.168.1.5). How do I set the eth0 ip to connect to the inverter without providing the eth0 with a gateway or dns? Have I got this wrong? Should I be putting in the dns and gateway of my router in the eth0 settings as well?

Comment: You claim to have done various things but not how and provided no diagnostics. Do you expect us to guess?

Comment: Be aware that there have been [*allegations* of serious security issues](https://www.solarquotes.com.au/blog/sungrow-inverter-security/) with Sungrow. Maybe consider setting up `iptables`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your Raspberry Pi uses two interfaces: **wlan0** to connect to your local wireless router, and **eth0** to connect wired to the Sungrow inverter. With different interfaces you also have to use different subnets, each interface connected to a subnet. The wireless network (interface **wlan0**) uses subnet 192.168.1.0/24 with ip addresses 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255.

You set **eth0** to 192.168.1.6 and the inverters ip address to 192.168.1.239. This cannot work because these ip addresses are on the same subnet of **wlan0**. I suggest to configure **eth0** to subnet 192.168.2.0/24 and give it the ip address 192.168.2.6 and the inverter set to 192.168.2.239/24 (or what you like between 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.2.254 except 192.168.2.6), or in netmask notification: to 192.168.2.239 netmask 255.255.255.0.